# Text goes outside of colored box - how to fix?

Tags: fonts, boxes, width, colorbox

My coloured box should look like this:

[image]

but here's how it looks:

[image]

So the fonts are different and the colours are also a bit different. 
It is described by [this LaTeX code](https://pastebin.com/w3m2rvqM).

I would appreciate some help with fixing this. I see that the widths of the boxes are different but I can't find how to control this width, as well as the box font.

Comment: please always provide a complete document that shows the problem and allows people to test answers. People can not run a fragment especially if it uses undefined commands such as `\newmdenv` . With no document we do not now the font size nor the  page size that you are using. Presumably you get overfull box warnings and you need a smaller font, or a larger page size (smaller margins) but without knowing how you set them hard to say what you should change.  Just using `\small` might be enough.

Comment: better use tcolorbox instead of mdframed - much more powerful and also actively maintained.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see my edit, I've added a complete code sample.